# PhaseListener class not found

Tags: jsf, classnotfoundexception, ear, phaselistener

good afternoon!

Always I try to deploy my .ear application in GlassFish3, I get the stack trace below referring to .war file inside .ear. I Tryed to search some solutions in several sites, but nothing help me. I got these project ready from work and don't know what can be.

```
Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: 
  Source Document: jndi:/server/portal_education-war-0.0.51-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml
  Cause: Unable to find class 'br.com.portal.education.listener.FaseListener'.
```

My **faces-config.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <navigation-rule>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>index</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/pages/index.xhtml</to-view-id>
            <redirect />
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>

    <lifecycle>
        <phase-listener>br.com.portal.education.listener.FaseListener</phase-listener>
    </lifecycle>

</faces-config>
```

And my class 'FaseListener':

```
package br.com.portal.education.listener;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.application.NavigationHandler;
import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseId;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseListener;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import br.com.portal.education.entity.GoogleUser;


public class FaseListener implements Serializable, PhaseListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4438623717276074774L;

    @Override
    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        FacesContext facesContext = event.getFacesContext();
        ExternalContext ec = facesContext.getExternalContext();

        String currentPage = facesContext.getViewRoot().getViewId();

        boolean isLoginPage = (currentPage.lastIndexOf("login.xhtml") > -1 || currentPage.lastIndexOf("register.xhtml") > -1);
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
        if (session == null) {
            session = (HttpSession) facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(true);
            NavigationHandler nh = facesContext.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
            nh.handleNavigation(facesContext, null, "loginPage");
        } else {
            GoogleUser currentUser = (GoogleUser) session.getAttribute("userAuthentication");

            if (!isLoginPage && (currentUser == null || currentUser.getUser().getId() == null)) {
                // NavigationHandler nh =
                // facesContext.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
                // nh.handleNavigation(facesContext, null, "loginPage");

                try {
                    ec.redirect(ec.getRequestContextPath() + "/login.xhtml");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {

    }

    @Override
    public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
        return PhaseId.RESTORE_VIEW;
    }

}
```

The class is placed in:
.EAR File -> .WAR File -> WEB-INF -> classes -> br -> com -> portal -> education -> listener -> FaseListener.java
[Class Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3dnh.png)

Comment: You forgot to tell where exactly you have placed this class. According to the exception it's clearly not there where JSF expected it to be.

Comment: Oh Sorry, the project automatically place in EAR File -> WAR File -> WEB-INF -> classes -> br -> com -> portal -> education -> listener (Here's my FaseListener class)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3dnh.png shows a .java file not a .class file..? How exactly are you building the EAR? Manually or using a build tool?

Comment: I using the export option in Eclipse IDE, now that you mention it, I thought it was strange and went to check it out, in older versions all files are .class files, but in new exports all files have the two types, .class and .java, I build it right now https://prnt.sc/26q9vjl and will make a test if I can deploy now